# How can I tell Git Clone to not run my .bashrc?

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to create a git repository that I can clone using SSH from a different server.  To test, I:

On SERVER_1:

1. Create a `/path/to/test.git` folder.
2. Chmod permissions to 770/ and g+s
3. cd into `test.git` and run `git init --bare --shared=0660`

Still on SERVER_1:

1. navigate somewhere else, and `git clone /path/to/test.git`.
2. Success! Commit some new files and push up. Also success.

On SERVER_2:

1. Open up Git (I'm on Windows, so I'm using Git Bash).
2. run `git clone ssh://[username]@[SERVER_1]:/path/to/test.git`
3. get a `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Hell` `Unable to write to standard output: The pipe is being closed`

Didn't expect that. I'm able to SSH into SERVER_1 through SERVER_2, no problem. After a little bit of debugging, I realize that the SSH is trying to run my .bashrc (which has an echo statement of "Hello World" in the middle of it). So I'm assuming something in my .bashrc is getting in the way here.

My question is: is there a way to stop the `git clone` from trying to execute my .bashrc? Or at least fail a little more gracefully? Looking at the help pages, `--server-options=<option>` seems like a place to start, but I'm not sure what to put in there.

Comment: `git clone` itself does not run rc scripts. `ssh`, on the other hand, *does* invoke a shell on another machine. If that shell runs rc scripts, that's where this comes from. (If you have `git clone` use a non-ssh protocol, obviously things differ. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this.

When SSH invokes a command for a Git request, it does so using the user's shell.  As a result, the shell needs to be reasonably POSIX compatible and needs to not produce any output on standard output or standard error when invoked noninteractively.  You'd have to build a custom version of OpenSSH that had a different behavior (and therefore would break compatibility with every other SSH implementation) if you wanted this.

You'll need to adjust your `~/.bashrc` or other startup files not to print anything at all when invoked as `bash -c 'echo foo'` (except, of course, the output `foo`).  If that prints something, you need to move that to your `~/.bash_profile` or elsewhere, or redirect its output to `/dev/null`, so that it doesn't happen on SSH noninteractive operations.

Comment: `bash -c` doesn't run any startup files at all unless `BASH_ENV` is set (basically only for debugging).

Comment: Yes, that's true, but there are clearly some RC files being invoked here, and `$SHELL -c` is how `ssh` invokes the interpreter.

Comment: True if you feed ssh commands as args, not true if you pipe them through stdin. e.g. `ssh localhost <<<date` will not invoke `.bash_profile`.  ***will*** invoke. duh.

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet money your `~/.bash_profile` on that server is not checking for interactive logins.

You'll have a line in there with the command `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`, with the `~`  possibly spelled `$HOME`.  It's a common oversight, e.g.

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

which says if the file exists, source it.  Ordinarily this doesn't cause any trouble at all, because most people aren't doing non-interactive logins, but it's biting you now.  Fix it:

```
[[ $- = *i* && -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

which reads, "if the shell options have an `i` in them, i.e. the shell is interactive, and there's a `~/.bashrc`, source it.